# validate controller only with images in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

hi i have given my attachment model:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
  has_attached_file :attach,
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                    :url => ":s3_domain_url",
                    :path => "/contents/:id/:basename.:extension"
  validates_attachment_content_type :attach,
                                    :content_type => ['application/msword',
                                                       'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
                                                       'application/pdf',
                                                       'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png']
end
```

i am using these content type some where in my application so that i can not change these content type. so i decide to set validation at controller site. i have given:

```
def create
 @designation = Designation.create(designation_params)
 if (@designation.attachment.attach_content_type.present? &&
 (@designation.attachment.attach_content_type.to_s =~ /image\/.*/)) || @designationerrorse.present?
 redirect_to designations_path, notice: I18n.t('designation_created')
 else
 render :action => :new
 end
end
```

code in designation model:

```
has_one :attachment, as: :attachable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachment
```

but it does not functioning properly.if i submit form with file field blank then it give me this error:

> undefined method `attach_content_type' for nil:NilClass

how to implement these validation so that designation accept only images and if it is blank? send me error message ***can't blank***. please guide me. thanks in advance

Comment: `validates_attachment :attach, :presence => true, :with => %r{\.(rar|tar|zip)$}i,
  :size => { :in => 0..10.kilobytes}`

Answer (score 1):

`validates_attachment :attach, :presence => true, :with => %r{\.(rar|tar|zip)$}i, :size => { :in => 0..10.kilobytes}, :if => Proc.new{|f| f.attachable_type == 'Designation' }`

This validation will be called when attachment will be of Designation class

Comment: i can't do any change in attachment model. because other content types are used by another model.i want to set only image in designation model

Comment: is it a polymorphic association of designation and attachment?

Comment: attachment is polymorphic only because attachment is used multiple times for different different purposes. designation and attachment has has_one association

Comment: check my updated code..this validation will be called only if attachable_type is Designation..so you can add this validation in attachment.rb

Comment: i can;t change model code. @test please check controller.

Comment: whatever validation I am writing will only be called when attachable_type is Designation so why can't you change the code of your model?

Comment: controller should not contain more logic..model is used for handling logic

Comment: why can't you check my answer?

Comment: undefined method `attach_content_type' for nil:NilClass

Comment: you are having attach_content_type column in attachments table..right?

Comment: ya i have this column

Answer (score -1):

you can use its own validation method like this:

```
validates_attachment :attach, :presence => true, :with => %r{\.(rar|tar|zip)$}i, :size => { :in => 0..10.kilobytes}
```

Comment: what is difference between your and my answer?